# On key up how to add the decimal value in jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

On Key up how to add the decimal value after entering the value ?

for ex : i entered the value 10 result should be 10.00 .

If i added like 10.50 result should be 10.50.How can i acheive this ?

**Jquery**  [**Demo Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/ecDmn/1/)

```
$("#txtQty").keyup(function() {
    var $this = $(this);
    $this.val($this.val().toFixed(2));        
});
```

Comment: dont use keyup. bcoz u cant type more than one number

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/ecDmn/116/ refer this link

Comment: Have none of the answers helped? Let me know if you need more help

Answer (score 3):

Use `parseFloat`, then `toFixed`

```
  $this.val(parseFloat($this.val()).toFixed(2));
```

Also, its better to use `change` rather than `keyup` because `keyup` does not allow change values midway in the textbox

```
$("#txtQty").change(function() {
    var $this = $(this);
    $this.val(parseFloat($this.val()).toFixed(2));        
});
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/ecDmn/112/)

Comment: Try typing 10.5 it gives 10.00

Comment: i give a upvote for that but that is what not my expected answer @AmmarCSE

Comment: @QuestionUser, what are you looking for exactly?

Answer (score 1):

You have to first convert to `float` and then use `toFixed` to add two digits after decimal.

Also, instead of `keyup` event, you should use `blur` event.

Try this:

```
$this.val(parseFloat($this.val()).toFixed(2));
```

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/tusharj/ecDmn/113/

Comment: please add some description on what you have done to solve the problem

Comment: i cant delete the value again.please check the fiddle ? http://jsfiddle.net/ecDmn/111/

Comment: @QuestionUser That's because you are using `keyup` event. https://jsfiddle.net/tusharj/ecDmn/113/

Comment: i cant give the value like 10 ?

Answer (score 0):

```
$(this).val(parseFloat($(this).val()).toFixed(2));
                 (or)
$(this).val(Number($(this).val()).toFixed(2));
```

Answer (score 0):

I know that's more like an overkill, but suggested solutions don't really look nice and neat (blinking letters, NaN when you enter letters, etc).

Try this:

```
$("#txtQty").keypress(function(e) {  
    var keyCode = e.keyCode || e.which;
    if ([8, 9, 13, 37, 39, 46].indexOf(keyCode) != -1) {
        // backspace, tab, enter, left-array, right-arrow, delete
        return;
    }

    var input = $(e.target || e.srcElement);
    var regex = /^[0-9]+[.,]{0,1}[0-9]{0,2}$/;
    var key = String.fromCharCode(keyCode);

    var selection = input.getSelection();
    var stringPart1 = input.val().substring(0, selection.start);
    var stringPart2 = input.val().substring(selection.end, input.val().length);
    var newValue = stringPart1 + key + stringPart2;

    if (!regex.test(newValue)) {
        e.returnValue = false;
        if (e.preventDefault) e.preventDefault();
    }    
});
```

This code prevents entering symbols that will result in violating the Regex, so display is always in **00.00** format.

This code requires jQuery and [rangyinputs](https://github.com/timdown/rangyinputs) tiny jQuery plugin for managing of user-selection. But if you want, you may write your own code for this or just give-up (or forbid) range selection in the text-box.

[**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/ecDmn/115/)

Good luck.